# How to add inner shadow to image using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I need to add inner shadow to image using imagemagick `convertor` like shown in the image below, can someone guide me
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick by creating a white image, then blurring it.  Then multiply it by the input.

Unix Imagemagick 6 syntax:

Input:

[image]

```
convert barn.jpg \
\( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 -virtual-pixel black -blur 0x10 \) \
-compose multiply -composite barn_inner.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I add shadow from top & left only and keep right & bottom as original?

Comment: and can I change color of the shadow from black to any like `#ff0000`

Comment: Yes, change `-virtual-pixel black` to `-background "#ff0000" -virtual-pixel background`